# How to detect changes to an element on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down menu that depending on the selection, I want to show/hide another element.

At the moment the html looks like so:

```
<div class="main-element">
  <div class="something">
      <span>Off</span>
      <select name="example">
           <option value="off" selected="selected">Off</option>
           <option value="on">On</option></select>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

When you click on the drop down menu and click on On, the span changes to
`<span>On</span>` (the user sees On as the selected option)

and if you save the changes, then the On option has the `selected="selected"` on refresh.

All good so far, but I want to do things on the fly, so when the user changes the select drop down to off/on, I want another element to show/hide.

How can I do the following in javascript?

```
If main-element select is clicked {
  if <span>On</span> exists { then show X element }
  else { hide X element}
}
```

So that it shows/hides `X` element on the fly, and not just on the first load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7kt/2/)

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var theValue = $('option:selected').val();
    if (theValue == 'on') {
         $('.hidden').show(); 
        $('span').html('On');
    } else {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $('span').html('Off');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"And if you save the changes, then the On option has the selected="selected" on refresh"... you'll need to do that with cookies or session variables.

To change the span when you change the select input:

HTML:

```
<span id="span">Off</span>
<select id="example" name="example.....
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("example").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = document.getElementById("example").value;
}
```

Basically that.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/wmh6b/

Or, if you fancy jQuery, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/wmh6b/1/